# Canada vs. Australia for the academic career

Tags: phd, research-process, career-path, computer-science, funding

Two days ago I was in discussion with a colleague of mine about the possible PhD studies destinations. We both agreed that the chances of getting post-Doc job or any full position are higher in the country we finish PhD (Maybe you have different opinion). However, we ended up discussion two potential (native English-speakers) countries, namely, Canada and Australia. We both had a vague idea about post PhD stage (academia or industry), so we had not much to share. My question is which country is *generally* better in terms of the following (computer science field):

- Research sector prospects (is there any studies indicate which country has stronger research profile in computer science - my gut feeling is Canada at least from  the world universities ranking in computer science)
- Academic career path (What are the possible career paths for PhD graduates? (tenure track, postdoc, lab researchers ... etc.).
- Finance benefits (taking into account the living cost in both countries, which of the countries, the academic career stand stronger comparing to the industrial jobs in terms of financial benefits)

Any advice to improve the question is most welcomed.

Comment: This seems far too broad.

Comment: @NateEldredge It is disappointing that I am almost sure that who voted to put this question on hold have not read the entire post down to the last line.

Comment: I'm voting to leave closed for now, and I've read it all. I'd suggest narrowing down what you mean by your bullet points, or asking about one or two of them at a time in separate questions. Your third bullet, "Job chances..." is almost specific enough, but even that seems hard to answer, as there are an awful lot of personal factors involved, and separate sectors of computer science to consider on the job market even within academic or industrial and not both.

Comment: The reviewers and voters are acting as they're supposed to. The problem is that this a very broad, opinion-based question. "Better" is just too unspecific a criterion to allow for a reasonable answer.

Comment: @aeismail Thank you, I tried to narrow down my questions. I hope it is easier to answer now

Comment: I don't think I follow your parenthetical in the first (edited) bullet: Is your gut feeling that Canada has *no* world class CS, or that it *does*, where Australia does not?

Comment: @MatthewG. I said that my gut feeling is Canada has *stronger* profile in CS research. My analysis is based on the universities ranking where Canada has much more universities in the top ranking universities in the world comparing to Australia. That does not mean Australia has some strong Universities. On top of that, this is only one metric, I posted the question seeking approval, disagreement and more factors

Comment: @Hawk Oh! Ok, I totally mis-parsed your sentence, leading to an ambiguity. Mea culpa.

Comment: Just a quick comment though, about 20% of the institutions in Canada would require you to have a working knowledge of French to become a professor (University of Montreal, University Sherbrooke, University Laval, etc.). This is something to take into account, especially since a strong portion of CS research (at least related to deep learning and machine learning) takes place in Montreal.